# Team Explorer 2008: Executing a query brings up a certain work item instead of a list of results

Tags: system, explorer, workitem

Strange problem I'm having here:
When I run a work item query in Team Explorer 2008, instead of getting a list of results as usual, I'm getting a single work item (always the same one, the query is okay though).
However, when I click "Edit query" I get the correct list of results below the editor.
I don't know what causes this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

May be your result list is older one and not updated with new result; try to close & open visual studio ;).